# Tachshitim on Shabbath

Tags: halacha, shabbat, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot, maseches-shabbos, jewelry

The Gemara Shabbath (several pages, but look anywhere from 59a through at least 62a for several discussions) contains a great deal of discussion about wearing "Tachshitim" (ornaments/jewelry) on Shabbath and whether or not it is considered carrying outside.

I think I must have missed something, though. About half the time that the Gemara concludes that something is a Tachshit, it says it is therefore totally fine for someone to wear outside on Shabbath, but the other half of the time the Gemara concludes that something is a Tachshit, it concludes that it is therefore *forbidden* for someone to wear it outside on Shabbath.

Which is it?  Is it permissible or forbidden to wear a Tachshit on Shabbath?

---

**This question is part of the [Daf Yomi Challenge](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1325/5).**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An edition of [The Shabbos Weekly Halachos Series on Hilchos Shabbos](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/ostroff/archives/shabbos4_36.htm) provides the following answer which fits with what I was taught.

> Background: although jewelry and ornaments are not ‘clothing’
> nevertheless they serve a function and wearing them on Shabbos is not
> considered carrying, provided that they are worn in the regular
> manner. [2]
>
> Chazal however were concerned that one would remove one’s
> jewelry to show to a friend and carry it in a reshus harabim (a public
> domain) and transgress the issur of carrying. They therefore
> prohibited wearing most jewelry.
>
> Most jewelry and ornaments may be
> worn nowadays because the Rama writes [3] that women do not remove
> their jewelry to show their friends and therefore the major concern is
> removed. The explanation being that in former times pieces of jewelry
> were not common and women would wear them only on Shabbos, thus they
> would show their trinkets to friends. As jewelry is much more common
> nowadays and worn all the time, this no longer applies.
>
> As mentioned,
> the prevalent custom is to wear jewelry but there is room to be
> mehader and not to rely on the various leniencies, [4] especially in
> big cities that are likely to be a reshus harabim d’oraisso.
>
> [2] Based
> on many se’ifim in simonim 310 and 303. See also SS”K 18:12.
>
> [3] Simon
> 303:18.
>
> [4] Bi’ur Halacha simon 303:18  Shulchan Aruch
> HaRav simon 303:23, SS”K 18:12.

Comment: So my confusion is basically stemming from the fact that the Gemara is weaving in and out of related discussions quite fluidly, and sometimes it's discussing the Torah Isur/Heter of wearing something vs. carrying something, and sometimes it's discussing the rabbinic Isur/Heter of wearing something lest it come to be carried? (Say 'yes', because this is what I've concluded on my own, and otherwise I'm lost!)

Comment: Yes. IIRC, there are some things which are not tachshitim and even if worn will be considered as carrying; there are tachshitim where there is no worry of "lest it come to be carried" and are mutar to wear and there are tachshitim where there **is** a worry of "lest it come to be carried" where there is a rabbinic prohibition.