# Wearing reflective armband in place without an eiruv

Tags: shabbat, see-sight-vision-blind, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

In SA OC Siman 301 it's discussed many of the things a person can and can't go out with on Shabbos in a place where there is no eiruv.

Is one allowed to wear a armband or wristband on Shabbos  with some sort of the reflective material on it in a place where there is no Eiruv? This way at night cars will better be able to see the Orthodox Jews crossing the streets. As well this is only worn at night and not during the day at all (it's taken off when one arrives in shul obviously and a person probably wouldn't want to wear it at all during the day.) What is this similar to if anything in regards to what it says in SA OC Siman 301? What other comparisons or examples or proofs to this could be give?

Comment: Is this different than a bracelet because it's for safety and not decoration?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman I don't know, that's why I'm asking. Maybe it is, maybe it isn't.

Comment: The poskim discuss wearing sunglasses on Shabbos. I was trying to work out if maybe this is similar since it's used to "protect"?

Answer (score 4):

After a recent fatal accident at night in Manchester UK, Dayan G Krausz of [Manchester Beis Din](http://www.mbd.org.uk/) and Rav M M Schneebalg of [Machzikei Hadass](http://www.jewishgen.org/jcr-uk/Community/m23_machzikei/index.htm) put out a joint notice encouraging people who walk at night in dark places to use these reflective armbands and **specifically stating they may be worn on Shabbos.**

Comment: I assume they were addressing all concerns, including Muktzeh as well as carrying (the concern in the question)?

Comment: Is there an Eruv in Manchester?

Comment: @DoubleAA As far as I know and have heard in the past there is no eiruv in all of England. Perhaps someone could correct this.

Comment: Eiruv in [London](http://www.nwlondoneruv.org/); [Edgware](http://www.edgwareeruv.org/). [**Not yet** Manchester](http://www.manchestereruv.org.uk/). See also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_eruvin#United_Kingdom)

Comment: I've seen similar notices on flyers and in newspapers in America, with big rabbis who signed (though I don't remember which)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously this does not address the S"'A or later Posekim, but it would seem from the Gemara that this would qualify as a [Tachshit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22585/5). I don't know how it could be considered anything else.

As it is something you would specifically *not* take off outside while walking, I don't see how it would be considered something to be banned lest one come to carry it.

Of course, CYLOR, but going to the root of the Halachah, and given the many examples and logic provided in the Gemara, I would think it should be ok to wear.

Comment: What is your proof from the Gemorah that this qualifies as a tachshit?

Comment: Nothing specific, just the ongoing discussion in the Shakla VeTarya that makes me think so. It's a bracelet, but it's not gold; it's something that isn't only worn by women; it's not a weapon; you wouldn't show it off to someone, etc. etc.

Comment: @Yehoshua, again, I'm not a Rav, and I'm not able to cite later authorities on what constitutes a Tachshit. But the Sugya is a long one, and it goes back and forth with all kinds of descriptions in the Gemara. Just a hunch of mine.

Comment: So this question doesn't have "1 Answer" so far it has "1 Hunch" ;)... I understand what you're saying...Al pi the clalim I'm having a hard time trying to say why it shouldn't be allowed however don't feel clear enough to say it for sure is.

Comment: @Yehoshua, unfortunately, they didn't have reflector bracelets in the times of the Gemara or S"'A, so they didn't discuss it explicitly.